# EF Core query get the same result twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have written a query and I get for some titles double results because one table has 2 directors for the same code, it is possible to put it into a array ?

```
var allFilmAut = await(from SP in _context.TblSessionPerformance //ok
                       join FILM in _context.TblFilm on SP.FilmStrCode equals FILM.FilmStrCode //ok                           
                       join CINOPERATOR in _context.TblCinemaOperator on SP.CinOperatorStrCode equals CINOPERATOR.CinOperatorStrCode //ok
                       join DIMCINFORMAT in _context.TblDimCinemaFormat on SP.SessionIntFormatId equals DIMCINFORMAT.CinemaFormatId //ok
                       join ALTLANG in _context.TblAltLanguageValue on SP.FilmStrCode equals ALTLANG.AlvVntPk
                       join COUNTRY in _context.TblCountry on FILM.CountryStrCode equals COUNTRY.CountryStrCode
                       join FILMP in _context.TblFilmPerson on FILM.FilmStrCode equals FILMP.FilmStrCode // not okay i have here 2 Persons with 1 FilmStrCode i need here to make a list
                       join PERSON in _context.TblPerson on FILMP.PersonStrCode equals PERSON.PersonStrCode

                       where
                            //HO00006416 
                            //HO00006553   2 directors
                            //HO00006643 
                            SP.FilmStrCode.Contains("HO00006643") &&
                            SP.CinOperatorStrCode.Contains("1007") &&
                            SP.PeriodIntPeriodYear.Value.Equals(2021) &&
                            SP.SessionStrStatus != "D" &&
                            //SP.SessionCurGross > 0 &&
                            ALTLANG.AlfIntId.Equals(9) &&
                            FILMP.FpersonStrType.Equals("D")

                       select new
                       {
                           
                           OriginalTitel = FILM.FilmStrTitle,
                           SessionFormat = DIMCINFORMAT.FormatStrName,
                           LocalTitel = ALTLANG.AlvStrValue,
                           Directors = PERSON.PersonStrFirstName + " " + PERSON.PersonStrLastName,
                           FilmsNationality = COUNTRY.CountryStrName,
                           NationalReleaseDate = FILM.FilmDtmNationalOpeningDate,
                           FirstShowSessionDate = SP.SessionDtmRealShow,
                           Cinemaname = CINOPERATOR.CinOperatorStrName,
                           CinemaCode = SP.CinOperatorStrCode,                               
                           HoCode = SP.FilmStrCode,                   
                           SessionID = SP.SessionStrHosessionId

                       }).ToListAsync();
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem?

best regards,
Ivica

Comment: If my understanding is correct, the film-filmperson relationship is one-to-many. I.e. what you want is a collection of directors per single film. What you need is a [Group Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins)

Comment: thank you i will try i think this is the solution :)

Comment: Or, if you used navigation properties like the design of EF intends, it would be done for you.. Using EF and then writing every join out like this is like buying a car and pushing it to work..

Comment: never used navigation properties sorry, can you make some examples please ?

Comment: Ah  i think i get it.

var directors = _context.TblFilmPerson.Where(fp => fp.FpersonStrType.Equals("D") && fp.FilmStrCode.Equals(filmStrCode)).Select(fp => fp.PersonStrCodeNavigation.PersonStrFirstName + " " + fp.PersonStrCodeNavigation.PersonStrLastName).ToList(); with this query i get both directors